# Exact same link looks different on Newsfeed vs Timeline?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

my iOS app allows users to share to **"Facebook"** after they claim a deal at a restaurant. It shares correctly to their **timeline** with the custom title showing what the deal was, but on a **newsfeed** it doesn't include any of the parameters I included. Just shares with a generic title of the App. It looks pretty bad!

Also on mobile it looks like the incorrect version on both timeline and newsfeed.

Any idea why this happens or how to fix it?

First pic is it correctly on a **newsfeed**, second is incorrectly on a **timeline**. Same exact post!

[image: How it looks correctly on a timeline]

[image: How it looks on a newsfeed - wrong info!]

Comment: That's the way of facebook!

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar problems but using custom actions. If you can tell us what parameters you are posting that might help diagnose the problem. Also, I assume that the page you are linking to includes the correct metadata tags?

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I'm linking to an App Store page, so not sure. The parameters are just `name` and `description`. Also now noticing on mobile it looks wrong on timeline and news feed...